# Python: py2exe loses file path information

Tags: python, path, py2exe

My python script saves a file in  parent of **file** path:

```
desktop = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
desktop = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(desktop, os.pardir))
file_path = desktop  + "\\" + "text1.txt"

fo = open(file_path, "wb")
fo.write("blabla")
fo.close()
```

When I turn this python script into exe using py2exe, the path `file_path` cannot be found. How to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution here:

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/WhereAmI

Answer (score 0):

You have to run py2exe from the place of the modules you are transforming to executables.

edit: more exactly make sure you have your setup.py in that place and run it from there.

Comment: This line fo = open(desktop + "\text1.txt" , "wb") should look like this
fo = open(desktop + r"\text1.txt" , "wb")

Maybe there is your problem, because you have a \t there.